# Access the GNOME shell aggregate menu per keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, gnome-shell

[image]

Is it possible to access the aggregate menu, or system menu, located in the top right corner on the activities bar of the GNOME shell interface, with a keyboard shortcut? If not, can such a shortcut be created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there's no dedicated shortcut for the aggregate menu. You could use the `ctrlalttab.js` helper (also known as *the accessibility switcher*). Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>:

[image]

and select *Top Bar*, this will focus the first element on the top bar (that is, the *Activities* button). You then navigate with right arrow to the system tray and use the down arrow to open the  menu...
Not very convenient, I know, so here's a way to define a dedicated shortcut for the system menu:
You can invoke `gnome-shell` evaluator via `dbus` and call the `open()` or `toggle()` methods on that particular shell element:

```
gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.Shell -o /org/gnome/Shell -m org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu.menu.toggle();'
```

or

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu.menu.open();'
```

So, it's only a matter of going to *Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts* and assign a shortcut to one of the above commands.