# How to unlock Gnome3 screen from command line?

Tags: gnome3, screen-lock, screensaver

This had been [asked before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107787/how-can-i-trigger-the-screensavers-locking-feature-using-d-bus-from-the-command/107789#107789). But existing answers to not seem to function on newer Gnome 3 versions (I have 3.14.0). Instead the following error message is received:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.ScreenSaver was not provided by any .service files
```

So, what is the way to unlock Gnome 3 from the command line theses days?

Comment: Just curious... how do you access the command line if the screen is locked ?

Comment: Via SSH.... Or lets say you want a cron script to unlock for you at a certain time of day

Comment: The best place to ask about this is gnome-shell mailing list... The code has been moved to gnome-shell... you can easily lock the screen via `Main.screenshield.lock()` but no idea if you can unlock it (there's no  `unlock()` function...)

Comment: That is the name on the JavaScript function that does the locking right? I've seen that in the source of some shell extensions. I do know the shell JavaScript API is available to extensions and from the "Looking Glass" tool. But is it somehow available for access by external processes such as command-line tools?

Comment: Sure, replace everything after `Main.` [in my answer here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224192) with `screenshield.lock();'`

Comment: Great! This opens up possibilities.... I wish this dbus evaluator thing was (better) documented...

Comment: I meant `screenShield` (the second `S` is a capital one)... What is it that you need documented ? You can find all the stuff that you can `eval` via `looking glass`...

Comment: I mean the existence of the DBUS evaluator itself and the possibility to send over JS expressions  to be evaluated. This answers a major part of my question - the general ability to do _anything_ in Gnome Shell from the command line...